# ReCaptcha doesn't work when used with Polymer in Firefox and IE

Tags: polymer, recaptcha, web-component

For some reason Polymer and recaptcha will on work together in Chrome, Safari, and Opera, but not IE or Firefox. When clicking the checkbox for "I am not a Robot" in Firefox/IE the following error message appears in the console and the captcha/challenge image is never displayed:

**TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug as confirmed here :
https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-recaptcha/issues/5